# How to get the selected values from CSS multi select box created using <div> tag

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webforms

I was searching for a nice CSS multi select drop-down list form control on the web and found a free CSS multi select form control at: [FreeFrontend.com Selectionator](https://codepen.io/maggiben/pen/ubHiy)

I have put this CSS multi select drop-down list on my ASP.NET webform:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="select" ng-model=""></div>
</div>
```

and tried to get the items selected by the users by using the C# (code behind) code:

```
string UserSelectedValues = Request.Form["select"];
```

But I could never get the selected values using Request.Form["select"]

Probably because the code for this multi-select box is in the form

```
<div id="select" ng-model=""></div>
```

and not in the form

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="select" runat="server">
```

How can I get the multiple selected values on this div based CSS selectbox control in the C# (code behind)?

Comment: multiple select values should be in a form with a `<select multiple>` tag. You get catch the values on the server side after a request is made.

Comment: Side note: `asp:DropDownList` returns single selected value. To fetch multiple selected values, `asp:ListBox` is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the comments but the problem is, I don't think I can simply change the code for this good looking multiple select drop-down control which is based on CSS <div> code to <select multiple   or  asp:ListBox and make it work.

Comment: Try adding runat server? `<div runat="server" id="select" ng-model=""></div>`. Doubtful but give it a try.